# Unable to attached the articles to case and also once article publish cant see it in the publish list

Tags: knowledge

I am trying to attached the articles to case and also when I am creating and publishing article, that article I dont see it in the List why ??

**Goto Case --> Open any case --> click on any case (say 0001048)**

[image]

Now click on **Find Article**

[image]

**then I see the following articles:**

[image]

**Then Click on any article, I dont see highlighted attached and return to case. I get this screen shot from another org** . Please guide

[image]

Comment: FYI everything you post here has something to do with Salesforce (otherwise it is off topic). Please stop applying irrelevant tags such as `[salesforce-communities]`, `[salesforce1]`, and `[salesforce2salesforce]` unless your question actually has something to do with one of these features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agents can now search for articles, view the article detail page, and then attach the article to the case directly from the detail page, rather than having to go back to the article list.'

In the past, an agent could only attach an article to a case from the Article Search Results list. However, they most often have to drill into the detail page of the article to determine if it is the right article to attach. If they have to go back to the list, it may be frustrating to determine which article in the list is the one they were just viewing.

When searching for an article from a case, not in the Service Console, an agent can click **Attach to case** or **Attach and Return to case**.

[image]

Buttons to attach an article on the detail page

After the agent clicks **Attach to case** or **Attach and Return to case**, they become **Detach from case and Detach and Return to case.**

When in Service Console, there is only Attach to case. Attach and Return to case is not needed, as you can just go to the case tab in the Service Console.

Button to attach an article on the detail page in Console
You can also detach the article once it is attached in the Service Console.

[image]

If the agent initiates the article search from a case, they can attach and detach the article from the article detail view.

Note
These options are not available unless the agent is coming from a case article search. For example, agents must start from a specific case that they need to attach or detach an article.

See Also:

IdeaExchange: Return 'Attach' and 'Attach and Return To Case' buttons to full view of an Article
IdeaExchange: Knowledgebase: improve attach article to case interface

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_knowledge_attach_article.htm